# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush does not work?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular8

I have a component that accepts input data:

```
<vr-savefile-dialog
  (saveCallback)="saveCallback($event)"
  [title]="'Save profile'"
  [data]="getDefaultProfile()"
  [action]="action.Save"
  [type]="'profile'"
></vr-savefile-dialog>
```

As you can see `data` is coming from `getDefaultProfile()` that can changes.

But problem is that when input data is changed I dont see chnages inside component in variable `data`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "vr-saveprofile-dialog",
  templateUrl: "./saveprofile-dialog.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./saveprofile-dialog.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

As I know `: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` works only when input data chnaged. But in my case not.

```
  public getDefaultProfile(): ProfileMenuItem {
    return this.profiles.find(profile => profile.isDefault);
  }
```

Where `this.profiles` is changed each time

Comment: Can you add  `getDefaultProfile()` in your code please

Comment: Yes, see it again

Comment: Do you have also `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your parent component ?

Comment: No, it is needed?

Comment: No, No. But it could have been the source of the problem. But it isn't.

Comment: With a `console.log(this.profiles.find(profile => profile.isDefault))`, are you seeing the same value ?

Comment: No always different object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202762/discussion-between-wandrille-and-jony).

Comment: With All primitive data types ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush only runs when reference is changes not the value.